# Connect to postgresql container from another container (Docker)

Tags: postgresql, docker, localhost, docker-compose, host

I have am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) and set up a postgresql container.

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

And the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    depends_on:
      - database
    command: ["./setup/wait-for-postgres.sh", "localhost:5432", "--", "node", "src"]
  database:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=tide_server"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

The problem is that when I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
server_1    | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
server_1    | psql: could not translate host name "192.168.64.2:5432" to address: Name or servi
ce not known
server_1    | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
server_1    | psql: could not translate host name "192.168.64.2:5432" to address: Name or servi
ce not known
server_1    | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
server_1    | psql: could not translate host name "192.168.64.2:5432" to address: Name or servi
ce not known
```

Now I have tried setting the host as `database`, `localhost`, `0.0.0.0`, and even the containers IP but nothing works, I have no idea what it should be or how to debug it, I am not 100% sure how `docker-compose` links the containers.

Comment: Passing in the command argument like `host:port` is a feature of the wait-for-it.sh script found here: https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh#L74 it's not something psql splits out for you, psql expects you to pass a port to the `-p` option. That said, 5432 is the default so not compulsory. 

In your example you've used `database` as the host so within the docker compose network that name should resolve. The errors posted above all show the usage of "192.168.64.2:5432", what happens if you use "database" ? I suspect psql will fail waiting for a password.

Comment: Yes it will fail with `psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`, I've provided a full solution in an answer.

Comment: If you use 5433:5432 it won't expose 5433 port, and you will get connection refused. As soon as you change it to "5433:5432" it will work. Tested with the official postgres:13.2 image(13 as well).

Comment: @John quotes are necessary?

Answer (score 4):

do not use depends_on. try it with "links"

```
    version: '2'
    services:
      server:
        build: .
        ports:
          - 3030:3030
        links:
          - database
        #environment could be usefull too
        environment:
            DATABASE_HOST: database
        command: ["./setup/wait-for-postgres.sh", "localhost:5432", "--", "node", "src"]
      database:
        image: postgres
        environment:
          - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
          - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres"
          - "POSTGRES_DB=tide_server"
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
```

for more informations https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Comment: Thank you for that, I have tried links and depends_on and both and still had no luck, cheers.

Comment: `links` is deprecated https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links , the advice is to use user defined networks instead. `depends_on` is fine, but it doesn't wait for the db to be ready, only for the container to have started https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on. It is intentional as per the docs "tutorial" link provided by the OP in this question, which is why they suggest `wait-for-it` and other ways to explicitly handle robust connection and reconnection from your application, not the container infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

May be an old thread to answer but I have been using depends_on with the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local

services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql:rw
        - ./deployments:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments:rw
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
   keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak
      environment:
        POSTGRES_ADDR: postgres
        POSTGRES_DATABASE: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: Pa55w0rd
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
        - 9990:9990
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

Comment: This appears to be a reply/comment on someone else's answer, not an answer to the OP's question in itself. Probably worth combining this (useful) point with your other answer.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial skips over a few things, and is confusing in that it mentions the `wait-for-it.sh` script, but then shows a much simplified version that doesn't work if you pass `hostname:port` as one argument to it.

I had a crack at getting this to work and both for future me and others I will add the steps below. I did this on MacOS, and have both docker and docker-compose installed as well as nodejs.

I don't have your node app handy so I used the one as described here https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

I have the following directory structure:

```
/src/package.json
/src/server.js
/.pgpass
/docker-compose.yml
/Dockerfile
/wait-for-postgres.sh
```

The contents of these files is listed below.

### Steps

1. From the `./src` directory run `$ npm install` (creates package-lock.json)
2. Fix pgpass permissions with `$ chmod 600 .pgpass`
3. Make the script executable `$ chmod +x wait-for-postgres.sh`
4. From the root directory `$ docker-compose up`

It will pull the postgres image and build the node app container.
When that's done it will wait for postgres and when postgres is up you'll see it ready.

## Files

*The src files are exactly as per the node js dockerize link above*

> /src/package.json

```
{
    "name": "docker_web_app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Node.js on Docker",
    "author": "First Last <first.last@example.com>",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.16.1"
    }
  }
```

> /src/server.js

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world\n');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

> .pgpass

*This uses the username:password `postgres:postgres` and is purely for development demo purposes. In the wild you will use some other method of secrets management and never ever commit a pgpass file to version control*

```
#host:port:db:user:pass
db:5432:*:postgres:postgres
```

> docker-compose.yml

- I have added the `wait-for-postgres.sh` script as a managed volume, in the original question it was bundling it in with the app src which was weird.
- I have also mounted the `.pgpass` file in the root user's home directory, which psql will look in for auto-password completion. If you don't have some method of supplying this then you'll get an error:

  psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
- Notice the command for the `server` container is referring to `database` which is a valid docker-compose internal dns name for the postgres container.

```
version: '2'
services:

  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./wait-for-postgres.sh:/usr/app/setup/wait-for-postgres.sh
      - ./.pgpass:/Users/root/.pgpass
    command: ["/usr/app/setup/wait-for-postgres.sh", "database", "--", "node", "src"]

  database:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=tide_server"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

> Dockerfile

- I have modified this from the node js tutorial, pinning it to the Debian "buster" version and also installing `psql` which it needs for that script.

```
FROM node:10-buster

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ buster-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list && \
    wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -


RUN apt-get -y update - && \
    apt-get -y install libpq-dev && \
    apt-get -y install postgresql-client-11

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

> wait-for-postgres.sh

- I have modified the script very slightly because I ran the "shellcheck" linter and it complained about a few things. I realise this script is from the docker tutorial page.

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$*"

export PGPASSFILE=./pgpass

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec "$cmd"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the host itself.

```
psql -h **"$host"** -U "<USER>" -c '\l'
```

You are passing a wrong HOSTNAME `"localhost:5432" / "192.168.64.2:5432"`

What I did is setup a `~/.pgpass` that has

```
localhost:5432:DB:USER:PASSWORD
```

and instead of passing `"localhost:5432"`, omit the port. Just use `"localhost"`

This works for me ...

Comment: It will help to specify the database using -d option

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, it's pretty much correct, if a little brief.